User created in linux has mismatched uid and gid
On my amazon linux ec2 instance, I created the group fungames and the user testuser-1. I then looked at the /etc/passwd and /etc/group file. The values added to the file by the linux subsystem doesn't seem to be consistent.
/etc/passwd
...
testuser-1:x:1002:1003::/home/testuser-1:/bin/bash

Base off of the entry above, the uid is 1002 and the gid is 1003
/etc/group
...
fungames:x:1002:testuser-1
testuser-1:x:1003:

However, the group file says the gid is 1002. Shouldn't the gid be 1003? Also why is testuser-1 in the group file?
I used the following commands to create a group and add user to the group
#Create group
sudo groupadd fungames

# Create a user
useradd testuser-1

# Add user to group fungames
usermod -a -G fungames testuser-1


It doesn't matter if the group and user id match or not.
If you want them to match, then be explicit when you run groupadd and/or useradd.
By default, when you create a user, a group will be created with the same name as the user. The -G option specifies additional groups of which the user will be a member.
